# Why is my flash object not displayed correctly?

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, apache-flex, iframe

I have a problem with a flash game. I have to implement it in an iframe on a webpage, that has to run in Firefox. The game itself is a own webpage, which loads the flash object with the library swfobject. 
If I open directly the game in Firefox, it loads and is playable. If I open the Developer-Tools, then the video of the game gets hidden, all I see is a white page. The music is still running.

The strange behavior is, that when i click on the body tag, the game is not visible. If i click on the header tag, the game is visible.
When I open the game in the iframe, it is not visible, like when the Developer-Tools are open.

I have some other games which loads perfect. The difference between them is the wmode. The game that doesn't work uses the wmode "gpu". The others "transparent". But the game itself needs the wmode gpu or direct, because it uses Stage3D or something.

The iframe is loaded in an md-dialog from the angular-material library. Also I use AngularJS.

**The game is working perfectly in Chrome!**

Do someone know how to solve this?

This is in the index.html of the game.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
        var swfVersionStr = "11.1.0";
        // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.wmode = "gpu";
        //params.scale = "noborder";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "Flash";
        attributes.name = "Flash";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "flash.swf", "flashContent", 
            "1180", "660", 
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
        // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
        //swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
    </script>
```

The index.html is getting loaded with:

```
<iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>

$('#iframe').attr('src',vm.urlD);
```

where vm.urlD is the parsed URL for the games index.html.

css sytles iframe:

```
iframe{
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border: none;}
```

Comment: Are you using Starling as game engine by any chance?

Comment: Not that I know... The game isn't developed by myself at all.

Comment: From experience I know that resizing the flashcontainer with Stage3D can cause the symptons you describe. But that can't be fixed from outside of the flash client.

Comment: But I do not resize the iframe or something else. And the people who developed the game have no clue what the error could be. Is it possible, that angular or angular-material kind of resizes the flash object?

Comment: I really believe the error lies within the flash client. If the 3D stage in flash is smaller then the viewport this issue arises. You can ask the game developers to play around with various Context3d profiles (see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage3d-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the size for iframe? Sometimes the flash embed isn't working well in some browsers if you don't fix the size for the container element. It is just working until you change the size of the browser (something like open Developer tools or resize the window. etc).

Example:

```
<iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="..."></iframe>
```

PS: You should show the codes that you have done for it to people can get the correct answers.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code. As you can see, the width and height is 100%. If I set it to fixed px, it still does not run...